# Android.Webview is not working for tracking url.how can open this url in my activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I have use android.webview in a activity that is working fine for all url but in case of any tracking url it'll show market details error in my screen.should open this url after open a  browser in web view.how it'll possible in my activity only.

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
    WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("http://trax.claym.in/click.php?c=209&key=c73n783g2tm2377yd73d6n5m");

        //  webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            if (errorCode==-10) {


                        String errormsg=description;
                String url=failingUrl;
                webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

                });
                /* Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    WebViewActivity.this.finish();*/
            } 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Log.e("error code:" ,""+errorCode);
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        @Override
        public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view,
                String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Log.e("WebResourceResponse" ,""+url);
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideKeyEvent(WebView view, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.shouldOverrideKeyEvent(view, event);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String myurl=url;
            Log.e("url", ""+myurl);
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    });
            //webView.loadUrl("http://trax.claym.in/click.php?c=209&key=c73n783g2tm2377yd73d6n5m");
        //webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/");
            //animation url
    //  webView.loadUrl("http://www.dogwonder.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/tumblr_ku2pvuJkJG1qz9qooo1_r1_400.gif");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Comment: have you find any solution for this.